# Windows will read this particular DVD which it usually doesn't, if it spins for a longer time

Tags: windows-8, dvd

I am unable to figure out what is wrong with my system.  My computer will  read this particular DVD sometimes and mostly it will not.

When trying to explore the DVD, I get error "Windows can't access this disc" (note: It does not say that the "disc is empty", the normal error which I generally get when I try to read a scratched DVD).

**OK now the mysterious part, I have noticed that every time the DVD spins for a longer time (like for 1-2 minutes), Windows will read it without any problem.**

Extra information:

- The DVD I am talking about does not have any scratches.
- I have tried cleaning the DVD Drive with a lens cleaning CD.
- The DVD was burned in multisessions.
- My system has Windows 8 installed.

Question I wanted to ask :

1. What makes the DVD spin for a longer period of time?
2. How can I make Windows spin the DVD for a longer period of time?

Comment: Looks like multi session is the culprit here...Take a look at this http://www.cdroller.com/htm/selector.htm ..The longer spin time may just be a coincidence or windows mounts the correct session after scanning the disk

Comment: Sorry...that's a paid tool....I will try to find some free "session selector"....you can search at your end as well

Comment: Have you tried the same DVD on another DVD reader?  If you get the same error there then the DVD is the culprit, else your DVD ROM/Writer

Comment: @tumchaaditya I think you are right multi session may be the culprit here. Let me check the "cdroller" utility it has 14 days evaluation period.

Comment: @StBlade I tried the DVD on another computer, got same problem.

Comment: @curious_kid Then I would say it is your DVD that is giving the problem.  Try writing to a different brand name of DVD and see if it gives the same issues.